# AngularJS: need to attach a selected collection to a model

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a CRUD and I want to some model to be linked to others. So on some update/create template I need to add some other model and save their id when submitting the form.
So I did a basic form that is served by my backend. Here is the part where I try to display the linked model:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in otherItems">
    <select ng-model="item" name="item" >
        <option value="1" ng-selected="item">
        <option value="2" ng-selected="item">
        <option value="3" ng-selected="item">
    </select>
    <a class="remove" ng-click="removeRelated(item)">remove</a>
</div>
<a ng-click="addRelated()"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
```

Note: otherItems could be empty at the beginning (when doing a create or when an item is not linked to any other related model's item).
So when one press add/remove it will trigger a controller's function:

```
$scope.addRelated = function (){
    if (typeof $scope[otherItems]=="undefined")
        $scope[otherItems] = new Array();

    $scope[otherItems].push($scope[otherItems].length);
};

$scope.removeRelated = function (item){
    console.debug(item);
    var idx = $scope[otherItems].indexOf(item);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        $scope[otherItems].splice(idx, 1);
    }
};
```

My problem is when I save I get the position of item in items (so it's always 0, 1, 2...) I won't have an array of selected ID. 
I guess there is something wrong with my addRelated maybe. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot to understand the idea since I may not be very clear:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a [plunk](http://plnkr.co) of exactly what you're trying to do? The code above looks like psuedocode.

Comment: I'll try to do a JsFiddle later. But you get the idea I guess.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?  http://plnkr.co/edit/6eqWL5

The markup..

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="otherItem in otherItems">
    <select ng-model="otherItem.selectedItem" ng-options="item for item in otherItem.items"></select>
    <a ng-click="removeOtherItem($index)">remove</a>
  </div>
  <a ng-click="addOtherItem()">add</a>
  <hr/>
  Selected:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="otherItem in otherItems">
      otherItem[{{$index}}].selectedItem = {{otherItem.selectedItem}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

The code

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.otherItems = [
      { 
        selectedItem: null,
        items: [1, 2, 3]
      },
      {
        selectedItem: null,
        items: [4, 5, 6] 
      }
    ];
  $scope.addOtherItem = function(){
    $scope.otherItems.push({ items: [7, 8, 9]});
  };
  $scope.removeOtherItem = function(index) {
    $scope.otherItems.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Sorry if it's off from what you're asking for... the question was a little vague, so I'm guessing at some of the functionality.

Comment: Very sorry for being vague. My english is bad. The dropdowns are already build from my backend code. So every added dropdown will be the same (a list of "same model"). Example: You can edit a user, that user is linked to 0 to any group. So when you edit a user you can link it to groups. I tought I'll do that by letting the user to add a new dropdown and select the group to match. Then when submitting the form every group id is send in an array called group for instance. On my real example I'm trying to make it DRY so I will use the code for any model to be CRUD (that may explain why I'm vague)

Comment: Maybe I should work with a template:
`<script type=text/ng-template id=related.html>
Related item: <select></select>`
And make a directive?

Comment: If you're creating an Angular app, I'd recommend not using your server to render data into html. Use Angular for that, and just have it load the data from the server via JSON.

Comment: I'm building the form with my server. Only the dropdown are made by the server. My server is restfull. I'm using an API to CRUD my model.